# Editing my question is not bumping it

Tags: support, specific-question, bump

I've edited [my question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686831/ssis-loop-a-list-of-connection-strings-in-a-master-package-executing-two-other) three times now as I progress with the problem.

But it's not bumping to the front page when I edit. I gathered from previous posts here on Meta that editing your question bumped it.

Has something changed or am I being thick?

Comment: Which question?

Comment: Question in question?

Comment: Your are funnier, but you type too much, random.

Comment: Your comedic stylings are superior, good friend random, but your superfluous verbiage and the subsequent typing it necessitates have doomed you to come up just shy.

Comment: Damn you, John Smithers!  Damn you and your succinct statements all the way to the roiling sea of fire and brimstone deep within the bowels of this world!

Comment: @Pesto: If you like prose, write a book! I do.

Comment: It's a pity English is not my first language, I would like to answer to all of you in verse.

Comment: Brevity is wit.

Comment: @mmyers: Rampant prolixity is the quintessence of artistry.

Comment: @mmyers: saying "WIN" is just not as funny, but clearly more concise.

Comment: Now I'm going to have to ruin my joke by explaining it: That's a shortened form of the Shakespearean quote "Brevity is the soul of wit." Kids these days...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I bumped it and it works. There a so many questions, it drops of the list very quickly. SO's success sucks from time to time...

Comment: Ah-ha. I had considered the possibility but didn't think the question avalanche was as fast as it must truly be! Thank you for checking.

Comment: It's Friday afternoon in Europe :-)

Answer (score 2):

Wow, the range is 6 minutes at the moment -- from most recent to least recent 48 on the homepage.